# Colorizing polygons based on a user-defined color scheme determined by the column value

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, colormap

I have a shapefile, and the population density for each polygon is provided in a separate CSV file.I would like to assign colors to each polygon based on a user-defined color scheme determined by the population density value. The colors based on the value may be

<10:yellow ; 10-25: green ; 25-50: blue; 50-75: orange ; > 75: red

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
shp=gpd.read_file('states.shp')
pop=pd.read_csv('population_density.csv')
nshp=pd.merge(shp,pop,on='name')
nshp.plot()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a dataframe with a column named `population` with values from 0-100.

You can use [`.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to

> Bin values into discrete intervals

and save the results into a new column named `popclass`. Then groupby this to plot each color/subframe on top of the same axis/plot:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

file = r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/world.shp"
df = gpd.read_file(file)

print(df.head(3))
"""       NAME  population                                           geometry
0   Norway          95  MULTIPOLYGON (((3.45729 -54.39007, 3.48666 -54...
1   Sweden          58  MULTIPOLYGON (((15.70533 56.11640, 15.72690 56...
2  Germany          38  MULTIPOLYGON (((6.79811 53.60444, 6.72242 53.5... """

bins = [-1, 10, 25, 50, 75, 9999] #Make sure you include the entire range of possible values with some tolerance. If the lowest can be 0, set the lowest bin to -1 etc.
labels = ["-10", "11-25", "26-50", "51-75", "76-"]
df["popclass"] = gpd.pd.cut(df.population, bins=bins, labels=labels)

print(df.head(3))
"""       NAME  population                                           geometry popclass
0   Norway          95  MULTIPOLYGON (((3.45729 -54.39007, 3.48666 -54...      76-
1   Sweden          58  MULTIPOLYGON (((15.70533 56.11640, 15.72690 56...    51-75
2  Germany          38  MULTIPOLYGON (((6.79811 53.60444, 6.72242 53.5...    26-50 """

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
handles = []
colors = ["yellow","green", "blue", "orange", "red"]
for (classname, subframe), clr in zip(df.sort_values(by="population").groupby("popclass"), colors):
    subframe.plot(ax=ax, color=clr)
    handles.append(mpatches.Patch(color=clr, label=classname)) #Create each legend item
plt.legend(handles=handles) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You make a geopandas data frame based on your 'states.shp' file, and a pandas data frame from your 'population_density.csv' file. Out of that big geopandas data frame you could make a smaller one, containing only those countries whose population density is listed in the pandas data frame. Then plot the big geo data frame with [geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot()](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.plot.html), displaying all the countries as grey. Finally, you could add a column for the population density to the smaller geo data frame and plot it too, with [a custom color map](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colorbar_only.html#colorbar-with-arbitrary-colors):

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# make a data frame with all the states of the world, based on Admin 0 – Countries data set from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/
all_gdf = geopandas.read_file('states.shp')

# read a CSV file with population density data to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('population_density.csv', delimiter='\t')

countries = list(df['Country'])  # countries whose population density we want to show
density = list(df['Density'])  # population density

# set the names of the countries as the index
all_gdf = all_gdf.set_index('NAME')
# get the data for the selected countries
selected_gdf = all_gdf.loc[countries]
# create a column for the population density
selected_gdf['density'] = density
# make a custom color map
cmap = (colors.ListedColormap(['green', 'blue', 'orange'])
        .with_extremes(under='yellow', over='red'))
bounds = [10, 25, 50, 75]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
# show all the countries with grey, meaning "no data"
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
all_gdf.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='lightgrey', edgecolor='grey')
# paint the selected countries
selected_gdf.plot(ax=ax, column='density', legend=False, vmin=min(bounds), vmax=max(bounds), cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(
    cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    ax=ax,
    orientation='vertical',
    extend='both',
    spacing='proportional',
    label='People per Square Kilometer',
)
plt.title('Country Population Density')
plt.show()
```

Assuming that you have something like this in your CSV-file

| Country | Density |
| --- | --- |
| Australia | 3.38 |
| China | 152 |
| Iran | 55 |
| Japan | 338 |
| North Korea | 215.46 |
| South Africa | 248.1 |
| Uruguay | 19.42 |
| Venezuela | 31.97 |

the output would be:

[image]